# Visual studio - Can't load any dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using visual studio 2017.

All of a sudden while merging a 2 `GIT` branches, my solution got all errors(`The type or namespace ....cannot be found`).

However the solutions compiles successfully.

I tried:

- delete VS cache
- restart VS
- even restarted the PC, still occurring.

[image]

Comment: Clear the bin folder, use the `rebuild` option to force a recompile of the solution.

Comment: Re-add your dependencies; this should solve your problem. It also happens when multiple users work on a single project, and each user is referring to another dll path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What usually helps me in this situation is recursively delete all bin & obj folders in the solution. Then close VS + open VS and rebuild. Voila... :)